# Mobilefirst platform local database connectivity with sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to maintain local sqlite database in MobileFirst platform.I tried with sql adapter. But its not successful. I dnt get what r the actually step or procedure for that.
Plz help me for that and suggest any tutorial which will helps to understand actual process for that...

Answer (score 0):

A local SQLite database in your application has got nothing to do with SQL adapters. Adapters are a conduit allowing you to send and retrieve data from a remote backend, not local in the device.

If you want to use SQLite you will likely need to use either a Cordova plug-in or use the Send Action API to interact with Java code in your app.

Read about SQLite (I'm assuming Android here...): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Read about creating Cordova plug-ins for IBM MobileFirst: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/

Read about Send Action API: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html